# how to configure auditing in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How do I configure WSO2 auditing in API Manger to log all successful/failure logins, various application access, API creations, API approvals, token generations, subscribing to/from APIs, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can see some audit logs at CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/audit.log file already in default. Responsible logging configuration can be found at,

http://umeshagunasinghe.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-enable-audit-logs-for-wso2-api-m.html

Also, the HTTP access logs will be in CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/repository/logs/http_access_.log. You can trace different actions based on your requirement from that.